# When wouldn't an <input> be rendered by Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I use Vue.js in most of my (amateur) frontend development and I am stuck with a simple case I cannot understand.

In the code below, the content of the search box (an `<input>`) is transformed into an Array, which is then iterated against to create some links (`<a>`):

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#search",
  data: {
    search: '',
    results: []
  },
  watch: {
    search: function() {
      this.results = this.search.split('')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<h2>a dropdown</h2>

<div class="dropdown" id="search">
  <input type="text" v-model="search">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a :href="#e" v-for="e in results">{{e}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Why isn't the `<input>` displayed?**

*Note 1*: When inspecting the code in Chrome, I see

```
<h2>a dropdown</h2>
<!---->
```

and such a comment is usually a sign that Vue.js has explicitly not rendered something.

*Note 2:* When refreshing the page, I see a very brief glimpse of the input field, so it is rendered, then hidden by (I assume) Vue.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you properly bind the `href` attribute like `:href="'#' + e"` it works. Vue.js somehow seems to get confused by that otherwise.